# Extending the header and footer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 to create a new project. As i am new in the laravel. so I am creating new page and directory structure is as follows:

```
-views
   - layouts
    - default.blade.php
   - page
    - index.blade.php
   - templates -common
    - header.blade.php
    - footer.blade.php
```

Now in page/index.blade.php I need to extend the default layout. my codes are as below..
LAYOUTS/DEFAULT.BLADE.PHP

```
@include('templates.common.header')
@yield('section')
@include('templates.common.footer')
```

and in index page i have defined the section but resulting the error as follows:

```
FatalErrorException in 1d36838b56f16e2e06a8567cdd5270af26ec6aa8.php line 1: syntax error, unexpected '__data' (T_STRING)
```

Please suggest me some solutions....
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your structure `templates - header.blade.php - footer.blade.php` no directory `common` in `templates`, which is in

> @include('templates.**common**.header')

Also check you have at first line in index.php:
`@extends('layouts.default')`